# Output row in text file with max value in specified column to new file

Tags: python, database, text, max

I have a fairly simple task I need to automate for an analysis. I have found similar questions on this forum but not applied to a plain text file, and as I am a python newbie I am not sure how to convert these solutions directly to my needs. So I'd appreciate any help.

I have a series of files in this format:

```
11 5012 1000 10036040.000000 1.089555 4.529811 0.150000
11 5013 1000 10038040.000000 1.089783 4.340549 0.150000
11 5014 1000 10039040.000000 1.090000 4.733367 0.150000
11 5015 1000 10044040.000000 1.090217 4.601943 0.150000
11 5016 1000 10044040.000000 1.090435 5.048237 0.150000
11 5017 1000 10046040.000000 1.090652 1.280908 0.050000
```

each file is named "data1-1", "data1-2", "data1-3" etc
The data is separated by single spaces and there is no header

I would like a script to go into each file, find the row with the max value in column 5 (eg value 5.048237 above) and to print that row into a new output file. 
In the end I need one output file that contains the rows with the max value in column 5 from each of the input files. So if there were 5 input files the output file would have 5 rows.

I hope this is clear, any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import glob, operator

fpout = open("result.dat","w")

for path in glob.glob("data?-?"):
    with open(path, "r") as fp:
        fields = [ line.split(" ") for line in fp ]
        maxline = " ".join(max(fields, key = lambda row: float(row[5]))
        print >> fpout, maxline
```

Comment: You forgot to say what iterable you were sorting. Also, the `max` function takes a `key` directly, no need to sort -- giving O(n-1) performance.

Comment: sorry newbie here, what do you mean by which iterable I am sorting?

Comment: @user964689: the comment referenced a fault in my suggested solution and got fixed.

Comment: How might I modify this script so that it runs in multiple directories, rather than having to put it in each directory with the data files? The aim would be the same, each output should be unique to that directory. The folders are all within one folder, so not a complex system. It just doesn't seem very efficient to manually run it in each folder of data I have. Thanks

Comment: @rocksportrocker it seems I need to specify that the data is in integer format, otherwise it prints the highest value as 9.99.. when there are higher integer values in the file. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: @user964689: look at the documentation of glob, then you should be able to modify the script yourself. The script operates on strings, so you get the max value in respect to lexicographic sorting. Do you have numbers with more than one digit in front of the radix point ?

Comment: Yes some have 2 digits in front. Thinking I need to save the data as an array first as I can't specify integer in the key of max as the key is already specified.

Comment: @user964689: changed it for numbers >= 10.0